# What could cause "Permission denied" for command `crontab -e`?

Tags: cron

Here's some output that I hope is helpful:

```
nick@home-sv-1:~$ crontab -e
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/nick: Permission denied

nick@home-sv-1:~$ echo $EDITOR
emacs

nick@home-sv-1:~$ ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs
ls: cannot open directory /var/spool/cron/crontabs: Permission denied

nick@home-sv-1:~$ sudo ls -al /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 2009-10-25 20:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 2009-05-18 01:19 ..
-rw------- 1 root root     612 2009-10-25 01:20 root
```

### Problem:

Crontab does not have setguid, and is not in the crontab group.

```
home-sv-1:~# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 32048 2009-08-30 03:34 /usr/bin/crontab
```

### Solution:

As root...

```
home-sv-1:~# chown root.crontab /usr/bin/crontab
home-sv-1:~# chmod g+s /usr/bin/crontab

home-sv-1:~# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 32048 2009-08-30 03:34 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Does `/usr/bin/crontab` have the `setgid` permission set?

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 32K 2008-09-28 14:07 /usr/bin/crontab*
```

If not, `chmod g+s` it (and if needed, `chown` **before** that)

---

Edit: Note that this only applies to Vixie Cron (used by most distros); other daemons (such as `dcron`) may use different permissions (`setuid`).

Answer (score 20):

Also it's worth checking out the permissions at /var/spool/cron/crontabs by

```
ls -al /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

In my case doing this showed that actually the user assigned to the crontab was 'whoopsie' which I assume means there was some error in setting up the user.

Performing...

```
chown <username> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>
```

Fixed this completely :)

Comment: This worked for me, but the problem was that the actual /var/spool/cron/crontabs directory was unaccessible to users, so the <username> file could not be created.

Worth checking that one out too.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I solved it this way.

```
sudo crontab -u yourUser -e
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Check for an /etc/cron.allow and /etc/cron.deny file.  If those files exist, make sure your user name is in /etc/cron.allow.

Comment: This would show a different error message - "You ($USER) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)"